# 4D instantons and the moduli space of N=2 on R^3 x S^1

Tags: research-level, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, instantons

I am reading the paper [arXiv:0807.4723](http://arxiv.org/abs/0807.4723) by Gaiotto, Moore, and Neitzke on wall-crossing. I would like to understand whether if the Darboux coordinates in the mutually non-local case contain the information on the corrections to the N=2 Seiberg-Witten prepotential due to 4D instantons or not. If they do, does anyone have an understanding of why this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can recover the Seiberg-Witten prepotential from the Darboux coordinates $X_\gamma$ (and indeed also from their "semiflat" versions $X_\gamma^{sf}$).  The reason is the asymptotic property

$X_\gamma \sim exp(\pi R Z_\gamma / \zeta)$

as $\zeta \rightarrow 0$ (up to a $\zeta$-independent constant).  Thus knowing $X_\gamma$ is sufficient to recover the central charge functions $Z_\gamma$.  The functions $Z_\gamma$ in turn are enough to determine the Seiberg-Witten prepotential.

Perhaps I should emphasize though that the idea of the paper is really to *begin* from the Seiberg-Witten solution, where all 4-d instanton effects are already incorporated, and then to incorporate the *new* corrections which appear upon compactification on $S^1$.